# Recursive set union: how does it work really?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, theory

I am currently taking the Scala course on Coursera on my free time after work, in an attempt to finally give a try to functional programming. I am currently working on an assignment where we are supposed to "calculate" the union of two sets that contain some object. I am intentionally omitting details as it's not really important to what I am trying to ask here. What is relevant, however, is that the sets are defined as binary trees, with each node containing an element, and two subtrees.

That being the case; the example `union` in the lecture is as follows:

```
def union(other:BTSet) :BTSet = ((left union right) union other) incl element
```

**Question1:** Quite frankly, even after having read the relevant FAQ and other forum threads, I still don't understand how and why this function works. There is absolutely no "action" done here in union implementation besides adding (the `incl` call) the element at the head node, it simply calls itself over and over again. I would be very appreciative of some explanation...

**Question2:** The course forum contains many posts stating that this solution is not efficient at all, and that it is not good enough. Seeing as I don't understand how it works to begin with I don't really understand why it's not good enough.

PLEASE NOTE that I do not, in any way, ask for a spoiler for the assignment solution. I am more than willing to "do the work for the grade" but I simply don't understand what I am supposed to do here. I don't believe the instructions and guidance provided in the course are adequate to wrap your head around the quirks of functional programming, thus I welcome any comments/answers that address *how to think right* rather than *how to code right*.

Comment: Maybe there's a different implementation for the empty set that you're missing?

Comment: So try drawing out what happens step by step!  Pretend other has one thing in it, and the thing you're calling has just a left, right, and element, but the left and right themselves have no children.  That should be enough to get the picture.

Comment: When you recursively go down you eventually will get an empty node as child, and that will invoke union implemented differently.

Comment: Basically the "this" set is getting dismantled and its elements are being added one by one to the "other" set.

Comment: The 2016 coursera discussion is illuminating as well: https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/discussions/weeks/3/threads/AzJ-4CLYEeag6wpD-92Rcw/replies/NsyjCSMIEeaSbhIJy3C38Q/comments/NqN3gXxxEeagQhLtAgFLAw?page=1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
  A
 / \  union  D
B   C

((B union C) union D) incl A
  ^^^^^^^^^......................................assume it works

(  B             )
(    \   union D ) incl A
(     C          )

(((0 union C) union D) incl B) incl A
   ^^^^^^^^^.....................................just C

(((C union D) incl B) incl A
   ^^^^^^^^^.....................................expand

((((0 union 0) union D) incl C) incl B) incl A
    ^^^^^^^^^....................................just 0

(((0 union D) incl C) incl B) incl A
   ^^^^^^^^^.....................................just D

((D incl C) incl B) incl A
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^.......................all incl now
```

Just write it out step-by step.  Now you see that union reduces to a bunch of incl statements applied to the right-hand argument.

Comment: I was just about to comment on here, so after having done more or less the same thing on paper; I kinda get what you mean. Although it appears as the recursion pops left-child, and adds it to the right hand. So I guess the second step should have been the other way around (C having B as a left-child), am I mistaken?

Comment: @posdef - It doesn't really matter, which is why I didn't ask, but yes, if `B union C` produces `C` as the root instead of `B`, you should flip those.  Depends on what `C incl B` does, which is what it boils down to.  (See where `C union D` turns into `D incl C`.)

Answer (score 5):

I gather that `incl` inserts an element into an existing set? If so, that's where all the real work is happening.

The definition of the union is the set that includes everything in either input set. Given two sets stored as binary trees, if you take the unions of the first set with the branches of the second, the only element in either that could be missing from the result is the element at the root node of the second tree, so if you insert that element you have the union of both input sets.

It's just a very inefficient way of inserting each element from both sets into a new set which starts out empty. Presumably duplicates are discarded by `incl`, so the result is the union of the two inputs.

---

Maybe it would help to ignore the tree structure for the moment; it's not really important to the essential algorithm. Say we have abstract mathematical sets. Given an input set with unknown elements, we can do two things things:

- Add an element to it (which does nothing if the element was already present)
- Check whether the set is non-empty and, if so, decompose it into a single element and two disjoint subsets.

To take the union of two sets {1,2} and {2,3}, we start by decomposing the first set into the element 1 and subsets {} and {2}. We recursively take the union of {}, {2}, and {2,3} using the same process, then insert 1 into the result.

At each step, the problem is reduced from one union operation to two union operations on smaller inputs; a standard divide-and-conquer algorithm. When reaching the union of a singleton set {x} and empty set {}, the union is trivially {x}, which is then returned back up the chain.

The tree structure is just used to both allow the case analysis/decomposition into smaller sets, and to make insertion more efficient. The same could be done using other data structures, such as lists that are split in half for decomposition and with insertion done by an exhaustive check for uniqueness. To take the union efficiently requires an algorithm that's a bit more clever, and takes advantage of the structure used to store the elements.

Comment: not to sound dismissive or negative but I am fully aware of what union of two sets mean. I just don't see how the elements from the first set are magically put together with the elements of the second (plus the root)

Comment: @posdef: Because at every point, it can turn the input into multiple smaller trees and a single element. The union of the smaller trees is done recursively, then the single element is inserted. The recursive "smaller trees" process stops when the smaller trees are empty. All the real logic is in the insertion here.

Comment: Just for the record, I accepted Rex Kerr's answer based on the timing. I appreciate the explanation in the edit just as much.

Answer (score 3):

So based on all the responses above, I think the real workhorse is `incl` and the recursive way of calling `union` is just for going through all the elements in the sets.

I came up with the following implementation of union, is this better?

```
def union(other:BTSet) :BTSet = right union (left union (other incl element))
```

Comment: this one actually works, the one above with the parentheses set differently it actually does not terminate for "large" sets. I dont quite figure out why though

Comment: I believe the original implementation, namely `((left union right) union other) incl element` runs in exponential time.  Consider how much redundant work is done by `(left union right)` every time `union` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

```
  2
 / \  union  4
1   3

((1 union 3) union 4) incl 2
  ^^^^^^^^^......................................assume it works

(((E union E) union 3 incl 1) union 4) incl 2
   ^^^^^^^^^.....................................still E

(E union E) union 3 incl 1 = E union 3 incl 1 = 3 incl 1
```

The following subtree should be **3** *incl* **1**

```
(  3             ) 
(    \   union D ) incl 2
(      1         )


(((1 union E) union 4) incl 3) incl 2
   ^^^^^^^^^.......................................expand

(((( (E union E) union E) incl 1) union 4) incl 3) incl 2
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^..................still 1

((1 union 4) incl 3) incl 2
   ^^^^^^^^......................................continue

((((E union E) union 4) incl 1) incl 3) incl 2
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^..........expand 1 union 4

((4 incl 1) incl 3) incl 2
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^............Final union result
```

Thanks @Rex Kerr draws out the steps. I substitute the second step with the actual runtime step, which may give a more clear description of the Scala `union` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't understand recursive algorithms unless you look at the base case. In fact, oftentimes, the key to understanding lies in understanding the base case first. Since the base case is not shown (probably because you didn't notice there is one in the first place) there is no understanding possible.

Answer (score -3):

I'm doing the same course, and the above implementation of `union` did turn out to be extremely inefficient.

I came up with the following not-so-functional solution to creating a union of binary-tree sets, which is WAY more efficient:

```
def union(that: BTSet): BTSet = {
  var result:BTSet = this
  that.foreach(element => result = result.incl(element))
  result
}
```

Comment: Mutation on itération is more than not-so-functional.