# Function always return Nil

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, recursion, for-comprehension

I am trying to resolve some anagrams assignments. And I can't figure out the problem behind getting always a List() when running my sentenceAnagrams function. Any Help !

```
type Word = String
type Sentence = List[Word]
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]


  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
  case Nil => List(Nil)
  case x :: xs => (for {z <- combinations(xs); i <- 1 to x._2} yield (x._1, i) :: z).union(combinations(xs))
}



def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
if (y.isEmpty) x
else {
  val yMap = y.toMap withDefaultValue 0
  x.foldLeft(x) { (z, i) => if (combinations(x).contains(y)) {
    val diff = i._2 - yMap.apply(i._1)
    if (diff > 0) z.toMap.updated(i._1, diff).toList else z.toMap.-(i._1).toList
  } else z
  }
}}
```

--

```
 def sentenceAnagrams(sentence: Sentence): List[Sentence] = {

    def sentenceAnag(occ: Occurrences): List[Sentence] =

      if (occ.isEmpty) List(List())
      else (for {
        comb <- combinations(occ)
        word <- (dictionaryByOccurrences withDefaultValue List()).apply(comb)
        otherSentence <- sentenceAnag(subtract(occ, comb))
      } yield word :: otherSentence).toList

    sentenceAnag(sentenceOccurrences(sentence))
  }
```

Comment: Bad code detected, sorry ). Return type of "List[Sentence]" and you are returning "List(List())". If you inherit Sentence from list it would be good to make some sort of "Sentence.empty". And on your topic: please provide code for your types.

Comment: "I am trying to resolve some anagrams assignments. " Seems probable it's "I'm doing the coursera course and would like to ignore the Honor Code". But, anyway, what have you done to debug this? Have you checked the various methods return what you expect in some simple test cases?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul : I knew that coursera assignments are well known. Yes I cheked the test cases , it seems that the problem in the substract method but it works well with several test cases.

Comment: @YurySukhoverkhov Done, Thank you

Comment: Note that `if (combinations(x).contains(y))`  does not change for each iteration through the foldLeft.  So you could check it just once. But you don't need to check it at all, as you are guaranteed y is a subset of x (read the comments in the Coursera file).  Also note that to be an Occurrence, the result of `subtract` needs to be correctly sorted...

Comment: The problem caused by my substract function cause the result is not sorted. Thanks @YurySukhoverkhov

Comment: @YurySukhoverkhov: I have another question concerning the Objsets assignements. I can not understand why when implementing the union function like that  `def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =  (left.union(right)).union(that).incl(elem)` I face a memory problem when running the main. I fixed this problem by changing the union method `def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =  right.union(left.union(that)).incl(elem)`. What is the difference ? thank you !

Comment: Dear user, I'm glad you resolved the problem. Please post code samples what I can quickly copy and compile/run. This helps a lot. Also perhaps it's better to start another question since your second problem may be interesting for someone else.

Comment: @user3621325, from memory, Martin Ordesky covers that point in the course videos...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul can you please provide the link for me ?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's a long while since I took the course. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217304/recursive-set-union-how-does-it-work-really

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul can you explain the problem ? the link posted above just explain how recursive union work. I am wondering why it is inefficient and why it ends by getting a memory problem. Thanks !