# Insufficient Memory behind a finite recursion

Tags: scala, recursion

I am doing the objsets coursera assignments. And I faced a memory problem

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 253231104 bytes for committing reserved memory.

when  implementing the union function like that

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left union(right)) union(that) incl(elem)
```

I fixed the problem by changing the union method to

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = right union(left union(that)) incl(elem)
```

What is the difference ? why iam getting a memory problem in the first case ? thank you !

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217304/recursive-set-union-how-does-it-work-really

Comment: the link posted above just explain how recursive union work. I am wondering why it is inefficient and why it ends by getting a memory problem. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I too have taken the Coursera course on FP with Scala and had the same problem as you.  I also came up with the same working solution.  The key to knowing why one works and the other doesn't is in the recursive decomposition of the function.  First, let's look at your first solution that does not terminate.

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left union(right)) union(that) incl(elem)
```

let's use a simple example tree and some arbitrary tree `that`:

```
val tree = NonEmpty(tweet1, NonEmpty(tweet2, Empty, Empty), NonEmpty(tweet3, Empty, Empty))
val that: TweetSet = ...

tree.union(that)
```

Expands to:

```
tree.left.union(tree.right)).union(that).incl(tree.elem)
```

Expands further to:

```
tree.left.left.union(tree.left.right).union(tree.right).incl(tree.left.elem).union(that).incl(tree.elem)
```

Now we can invoke the base case on the Empty TweetSets (tree.left.left and tree.left.right)

```
tree.right.incl(tree.left.elem).union(that).incl(tree.elem)
```

That's far enough for now, let's look at the second solution.

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = left union(right union(that)) incl(elem)


tree.union(that)
```

Expands to:

```
tree.left.union(tree.right.union(that)).incl(tree.elem)
```

Expand again:

```
tree.left.union(tree.right.left.union(tree.right.right.union(that)).incl(tree.right.elem)).incl(tree.elem)
```

Apply the base case for tree.right.left and tree.right.right

```
tree.left.union(that.incl(tree.right.elem)).incl(tree.elem)
```

After the same number of steps on each you can see that we have very different expressions.

Solution1 = `tree.right.incl(tree.left.elem).union(that).incl(tree.elem)`

Solution2 = `tree.left.union(that.incl(tree.right.elem)).incl(tree.elem)`

In solution 1, you can see that the `incl` call occurs on the left side of the next `union`:

```
tree.right.incl(tree.left.elem).union(that).incl(tree.elem)
           ^^^^
```

while in solution 2, the `incl` occurs on the right side of the next `union`.

```
tree.left.union(that.incl(tree.right.elem)).incl(tree.elem)
                     ^^^^
```

So we can see that solution 1 builds a brand new tree before the union with one less element than the previous iteration.  This process will repeat for every left branch in the tree that will be processed. An n^2 efficiency.  The memory allocation error occurs from creating n^2 new trees.  Solution 2 uses an existing tree as the left side of the next union and returns the new tree from the base case (efficiency of n).  To have an efficient union with the given base case, you must build up the right side of the `union` expression because building up the left side will result in exponentially more work.